# html meta refresh does not go to the URL

Tags: html, bash, meta

I am using this to ask the page to refresh after every 10 seconds, in CGI shell script:

```
                          pid=$!

                            if [[ `ps -p $pid | wc -l` -gt 1 ]]
                            then
                                    output="Program is running. Running time depends on the number of alternatively spliced proteins the submitted gene has. Results will be displayed here."

                                    echo "<html>"
                                    echo "<head>"
                                    echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='http://XXX/gene-to-structure/navnav.gif'"/>"
                                    echo "</head>"
                                    echo "<body>"

                                    echo "<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">"
                                    echo "<tr><td><img src=\"../../images/calc.gif\" align=\"absmiddle\"> <strong> $output </strong></td></tr>"
                                    echo "</table>"
                                    echo "</body>"
                                    echo "</html>"
                            fi
```

But it is not taking me to the "URL". After 10 seconds, it refreshes to the same page. Could you please let me know what could be wrong? Thanks much!

Comment: Can you use Ctrl-U in your browser to capture and post the exact HTML that your browser is receiving from this script?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a quoting problem, which is astounding because that hardly ever happens in bash. :-)  Try something like this:

```
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10;URL='http://XXX/gene-to-structure/navnav.gif'\"/>"
```

to see if that gets you closer. Examining the HTML the browser is receiving is an easy place to confirm whether you generated the exact HTML you intended.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but after it goes to the URL, it does not refresh? I was expecting it to refresh every 10seconds until the "$pid" is "-gt" 1. Could you please let me know what the issue could be? What I am trying to do is, while the program runs in the background, the browser refresh every 10 seconds with the URL given, and when the program ends in the background then the URL disappears and the output is presented in the webpage from which meta refresh URL was given. Thanks.